# Android action bar - tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to do this "Action bar" ?
Exactly i mean http://i48.tinypic.com/2s667hs.png such a thing.
it can be fit for Android 2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actionbar is 3.0+ only. Unless you go for a third party code such as ActionBarSherlock.

To do it native on android I suggest you a read on the developer guide post about the actionbar. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: This image is what I put on Android 2.3

Comment: oh ok, got it... so probably is a TabHost with a few TabsInside. It may also be a ViewPager with a PagerTabStrip (but I'm not sure these allows to use icons, only text)